What is the rationale behind `TransformedTargetRegressor` always cloning the given `regressor` and how to prevent this behavior?
The docs of sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor state that:

regressor object, default=None
Regressor object such as derived from RegressorMixin. This regressor will automatically be cloned each time prior to fitting. If regressor is None, LinearRegression is created and used.

What is the rationale behind cloning the given regressor each time prior to fitting? Why would this be useful?
This behavior prevents, for example, the following code from working:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor


X = np.random.default_rng(seed=1).normal(size=(100,3))
y = np.random.default_rng(seed=1).normal(size=100)

model = RandomForestRegressor()
pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('normalize', StandardScaler()),
        ('model', model),
    ],
)
tt = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=pipeline, transformer=StandardScaler())
tt.fit(X, y)

print(model.feature_importances_)

It results in:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(model.feature_importances_)
[...]
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This RandomForestRegressor instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

which is not surprising given that the model object is cloned by the TransformedTargetRegressor.
So, is there a way to prevent this cloning behavior and make the above code work?

We had the same issue, The TransformedTargetRegressor clones the regressor to ensure it's fresh for each fit, it lead issues with accessing model attributes in a pipeline. later we adpated RandomForestRegressor  to fit the model directly within the pipeline..

@Bhargav-RetardedSkills Thanks for your comment. Could you expand this into an answer to elaborate on what changes you made specifically? I'm still not sure how I could make the above example work.

All sklearn meta-estimators (except Pipeline) clone their base estimators; I can't confidently answer why the developers chose that paradigm.
But the fitted base estimators are always made available in new attributes: instead of
model.feature_importances_

use
tt.regressor_['model'].feature_importances_


One solution you can try like us is you can fit the pipeline directly rather than using TransformedTargetRegressor
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor

X = np.random.default_rng(seed=1).normal(size=(100, 3))
y = np.random.default_rng(seed=1).normal(size=100)

model = RandomForestRegressor()
pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('normalize', StandardScaler()),
        ('model', model),
    ]
)


pipeline.fit(X, y)

# access feature
print(pipeline.named_steps['model'].feature_importances_)

output
[0.34027344 0.34470309 0.31502347]

What is the rationale behind cloning the given regressor each time prior to fitting? Why would this be useful?
My hunch is due to Cloning provides consistency and safety, ensuring that the original regressor object is not modified - https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/discussions/23747
Ready to listen others perspective!..
